Unable to resolve dependencies. 'DependencyName 1.0.0' is not compatible with 'PackageName 18.1.10 constraint: DependencyName (>= 1.0.0)'
I'm trying to install a package with the Nuget Package Manager and I'm getting the following error:
Unable to resolve dependencies. '<Dependency.Package> 1.0.0' is not compatible with
'<Main.Package> 18.1.10 constraint: <Dependency.Package> (>= 1.0.0)'.               

where Dependency.Package and Main.Package are both company internal packages. My question is: why is the package manager giving this error when the package version is clearly compatible? What can I do to further debug this error outside of contacting the package owners?
